# Supporting RTL locales when drawing in custom views

Tags: android, android-custom-view, right-to-left

When I draw in my custom view using the Canvas, is there a simple way to draw for RTL locales without manually inverting coordinate calculations?

As a very contrived example, here is a custom View with the following in onDraw():

```
int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();
canvas.save();

mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h, mPaint);
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h, mPaint);

int size = h / 4;
mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
int paddingEnd = ViewCompat.getPaddingEnd(this);
canvas.translate(-paddingEnd, getPaddingTop());
canvas.drawRect(w - size, 0, w, size, mPaint);

canvas.restore();
```

It appears exactly the same in LTR and RTL layouts:

[image]

I know you can flip the Canvas using a Matrix or `canvas.scale()`, but this is not a viable option for more complicated scenarios, such as drawing text or other Drawables on the Canvas.

What is the best way to accomplish RTL drawing on a Canvas? Do I literally have to calculate inverted values for X-axis coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I could find, there isn't anything in the framework that automatically handles transforming the canvas (for drawing, as in this case) or that handles positioning views (for layout). In other words, I have to do that work myself using [`View.getLayoutDirection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutDirection()) to determine the layout direction and calculate accordingly. Since most drawing code works with the `left` position of the object, you can usually do something like

```
if (isRtl) {
    left = width - shapeWidth - left;
}
```

where `width` is the width of the canvas (or the area of the canvas you are drawing in, e.g. if you've already subtracted the amount consumed by left and right padding), and `shapeWidth` is the shape width. Then you add the shape width to `left` to get the `right` value.

A similar approach can be used for laying out child views.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call `canvas.scale()` inside `onDraw()` to flip horizontally result of all further drawing operations.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save()

    boolean isRtl = getLayoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
    if (isRtl) canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, (float) width / 2, (float) height / 2)

    //
    // do all your custom drawing here
    //

    canvas.restore()
}
```